# How to enter secure boot password on remote machine?

Tags: 18.04, secure-boot, dkms, wireguard

I am trying to disable/bypass Secure Boot on Ubuntu Server 18.04 to use [Wireguard](https://www.wireguard.com/). Unfortunately, my machine is remote and headless, meaning I cannot access it until the boot-up process is finished. This causes me to miss the prompt for entering the password and disabling Secure Boot.

Is it possible to bypass this requirement, enter the password, or somehow add the required key that allows Wireguard to work?

I tried finding alternative ways to disable Secure Boot such as [Dell's Script Utilities](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=9wyng) but unfortunately it is not available for Ubuntu Server 18.04.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.